# jqGrid is empty

Tags: php, jquery, json, jqgrid

I am building a small application. I have a PHP code which inside has a creation of jqGrid and also I have a servlet which sends a **string** of an array with JSONs inside.

The string looks like this:

```
[
    {"id":1,"firstName":"Amishay","lastName":"Vaturi"},
    {"id":2,"firstName":"Amir","lastName":"Bilu"},
    {"id":3,"firstName":"Michael","lastName":"Keidar"},
    {"id":4,"firstName":"Mika","lastName":"Spivak"},
    {"id":5,"firstName":"Ksenia","lastName":"Mosorov"},
    {"id":6,"firstName":"Rose","lastName":"Wahlem"}
]
```

The problem is I don't see it in the grid I made...
the grid code is this :

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'http://10.0.0.4:8080/api/students/all',
    mtype: "GET",
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    colModel: [
 { label: 'ID', name: 'id', key: true, width: 75 , height: 50 },
 { label: 'First Name', name: 'firstName', width: 150 , height: 50},
 { label: 'Last Name', name: 'lastName', width: 150 , height: 50}
    ],
    viewrecords: true,
    width: 780,
    height: 250,
    rowNum: 20,
    pager: "#jqGridPager"
});
```

I looked here and in the entire net to search for an answer.
I saw I might need to send a different json from the server. perhaps with more info such as records,number of page etc. I also saw I might need to declare a json reader in the jqGrid properties.
I did both.. still didn't work. It's like I didn't find a solution which meets my problem in a 100%.
I will be very happy to get an answer which works (:

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The *body* of the HTTP response is a string typically. Thus you have to use `datatype: "json"` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"` if you want to load the data from `url`. I posted more details in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is the usage of `datatype: "jsonstring"` instead of

```js
datatype: "json"
```

By the way you don't need to create hidden column `id`, because jqGrid assign the value of `id` property to `id` attribute of rows (`<tr>` elements). Additionally I would recommend you to use `loadonce: true` option, because the format of data which you use don't means server side paging.

I create the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/oc7uuh9q/, which used your data to demonstrate that all should work. I just modified your code a little to use new features implemented in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), the fork of jqGrid, which I develop.

Comment: first of all - thanks a lot! second, I do a get request and not a post request ( I don't know if something needs to be changed because of that besides the key "mtype" ). But my servlet returns only the string I posted.. doesn't it supposed to also send the page number,number of total records etc. in its response? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me.What you offered. btw - the id is not the id for the grid. it's the id of the student from the DB. the json string I return from the servlet is the one I posted. I don't know what is the problem.. even the chrome debugger doesn't have errors...

Comment: @NikolaiJakov: You are welcome! I used POST because of Echo service of JSFiddle don't support GET, but all works in the same way. Do you tried with `datatype: "json"`? Is it work? In any way you have to use `datatype: "json"` if you want that jqGrid uses `url` and `mtype`. If you use `datatype: "jsonstring"` then jqGrid expect that the data are already exist locally in as string. It read the data from `datastr` parameter.

Comment: @NikolaiJakov: Could you use Chrome or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to make HTTP trace and then append your question with **exact data** returned in the HTTP body. It could be that you data looks **not like you posted** but for example like `"[{\"id\":1, ....`

Comment: the change of the datatype doesn't work..but I understand. It needs to be json anyways. something else is missing... is it okay to use GET as mtype because from the demo I saw , they used get and I implemented the servlet that way...

Comment: I am new to the web world so do what you asked with the trace...I just don't know \:

Comment: I browsed manually the  URL "http://10.0.0.4:8080/api/students/all" and what I got is : [{"id":1,"firstName":"Amishay","lastName":"Vaturi"},{"id":2,"firstName":"Amir","lastName":"Bilu"},{"id":3,"firstName":"Michael","lastName":"Keidar"},{"id":4,"firstName":"Mika","lastName":"Spivak"},{"id":5,"firstName":"Ksenia","lastName":"Mosorov"},{"id":6,"firstName":"Rose","lastName":"Wahlem"}]

Comment: @NikolaiJakov: Just install [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), start it and open your page. You well see that Fiddler make HTTP trace automatically. You need find the GET request to `/api/students/all` and to see the content. You can find many good tutorials on youtube. Another problem which you could have is the usage of `http://10.0.0.4:8080`. You should load the data **from the same site** and use better related path like `/api/students/all` or `api/students/all`. Alternatively you could use CORS in the servlet.

Comment: @NikolaiJakov: Opening URL in web browser is the wrong way. It's another way as loading data via Ajax.

Comment: but my php is on a different VM. I have 1 VM which deals with web stuff.. like the php page which has the jqgrid and another VM which runs tomcat for the servlet and also mySQL.

Comment: @NikolaiJakov: Then it's wrong. If you add `loadError` callback to jqGrid you will see the error. You should place HTML page, which create jqGrid on the same web server, so that you could use `url` without server name and port name. There are another solution, but it will be more complex. You will have to modify your web site to support CORS and use additional options of jqGrid to send the CORS header.

Comment: The real life scenario is you have 1 machine which runs apache and php and another machine which runs tomcat for java servlets. I did that after a friend recommendation. the URL key in the jqGrid has to be a url of a different machine because this is where the servlet runs. There must be a solution for that.

Comment: @NikolaiJakov: Your friend suggested you not the best architecture of the solution. If you would really need to implement it you have to know the basics of Ajax security. You have to understand [the same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which **prevents** Ajax requests in your scenario. There are two main workarounds: 1) the usage of ["jsonp"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead of `"json"` 2) the usage of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Both workarounds **require** changing of the server code and jqGrid options.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial or an example that does it? changing the json to jsonp is no problem, but I have no idea what to change in the jqGrid options and what to change in the server... As I said, I am very new to the web world and I am willing to learn of course but in every example I looked at the internet they didn't have my issue...the url was always local like you said...

Comment: @NikolaiJakov: I don't use servlet myself. I use C# and ASP.NET (mostly MVC, Web Api and WCF). I repeat that I would recommend you to implement the solution where both HTML page, which uses jqGrid, and the servlet are of *the same web site*. The most important is to divide more complex problem in the parts which you solves *separately*. After you will have working solution you can make *additional modifications* to migrate the solution in your destination environment.

Comment: @NikolaiJakov: I posted you the first references (you can switch the textes to Russian, for example: [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0), [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)), you have to read it first and understand how JSONP and CORS works, then choose what is the best choice for you. You can start with JSONP and then, if required to migrate to CORS if required.

Comment: @NikolaiJakov: I would strictly recommend you to install [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and use it permanently in all your experiments. In the way you will clear understand what exactly will be send to the server and what returns the server back.